# How to add a Listener for focus done in cameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am trying to implement manual focus on CameraX. but i don't know how to check that where startFocusAndMetering completed or not.

I tried something like this

```
 val focusListenableFuture = camera?.cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(action)
```

I found that there is a method **isDone()** which can check weather focusing completed or not

how can i use it with **focusListenableFuture?.addListener()** to listen weather focusing completed or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`FocusMeteringResult#isFocusSuccessful()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/FocusMeteringResult#isFocusSuccessful()):

> Returns if auto focus is successful.
>
> If AF is requested in FocusMeteringAction but current camera does not
> support AF, it will return true. If AF is not requested, it will
> return false.

```
val focusListenableFuture  = camera?.cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(action)
focusListenableFuture.addListener( {
    val result = focusListenableFuture.get()
    val isSuccessful = result.isFocusSuccessful
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
```

Comment: what is executor here

Comment: For executor you can use `ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)`. I've edited my answer.